# Changing temporary file location from Mac to external hard drive using terminal

Tags: terminal, mac, backup, external-disk

I am using a Backup Extractor app to extract photos/media from a recent backup on my external hard drive. I successfully extracted photos from the backup and saved it to my external hard drive. Now I am trying to extract videos but I don't have enough space on my Mac to store the temporary files while it saves to the external hard drive. So I need to move the location of the temporary files to the Mac itself using terminal.
I don't want to enter the wrong code and have it mess anything up.

Would it be:

```
mv ~/.local/share/Reincubate Temporary Files/iPhone Backup Extractor/External Hard Drive 1/Temporary files
```

Reincubate is the name of the extractor app, External hard drive 1 is the name of the hard drive, and temporary files is the folder I want to move the files to.
I also received the location where it saves to from the app FAQ page.

Is that correct?

Comment: where did iPhone come from in your command?  you also have to do something about the spaces in your command, they won't fly.  You could use quotes around the names with spaces in it. like;  "Reincubate Temporary Files".

Comment: Either put quotes around the source and destination path and file as @jmh stated or escape them with backslashes like `Reincubate\ Temporary\ Files`.

Comment: Other than the issues with spaces in the command, what tells the program to use that temporary storage once you have moved the files there? Is there an option to point it to the new location? If not you may have to create a symlink from the old to new location